# ajax não retorna erro nem sucesso

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

tenho 3 funções ajax que estão a fazer post a uma api REST

```
//--------------------------cliente----------------------------------------------------------
  const urlattime = document.location.origin;
  console.log(urlattime);
  $('#entercliente').click(function () {

    password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
    if (password == password1) {
      let password_ = password;
      let password1_ = password1;
      let nome_ = nome.value;
      let email_ = email.value;
      let nif_ = nif.value;
      let morada_ = morada.value;
      let cod_postal_ = codigopostal.value;
      let cidade_ = cidade.value;
      let tipo_ = "cliente";
      
      

      $.ajax({
        url: urlattime+'/user/register',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
       
        data: { nome: nome_, password: password_,password1:password1_, email: email_, nif: nif_, morada: morada_, cod_postal: cod_postal_, cidade_: cidade_, tipo: tipo_ },
        success: function (data) {
          console.log("sucesso");
          window.location.href = "login.html";
        }
        , error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        }
      })
      window.alert("x");
     
    }
    else {

      console.log(password + "" + password)
      document.getElementById("coincidense").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  });
  //-------------------------------condutor -------------------------------------------------------
  $('#entercondutor').click(function () {
    
    password = document.getElementById("password_condutor").value;
    password1 = document.getElementById("password1_condutor").value;
    if (password == password1) {
      let password_ = password_condutor.value
      let password1_ = password1_condutor.value
      let email_ = email_condutor.value;
      let nome_ = nome_condutor.value;
      let nif_ = nif_condutor.value;
      let morada_ = morada_condutor.value;
      let cod_postal_ = codigopostal_condutor.value;
      let cidade_ = cidade_condutor.value;
      let tipo_ = "condutor";
      let matricula_ = matricula.value;
      let tipo_veic_ = tipo_veic.value;
      


     
      $.ajax({
        url: urlattime+'/user/register',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: { nome: nome_, password: password_,password1:password1_, email: email_, nif: nif_, morada: morada_, cod_postal: cod_postal_, cidade_: cidade_, tipo: tipo_, matricula: matricula_, veiculo: tipo_veic_ },

        success: function (data) {
          window.location.href = "login.html";
          
        }
        , error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
          window.alert('text status ' + textStatus + ', err ' + err)
          window.alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
      })

    }
    else {

      console.log(password + "" + password)
      document.getElementById("coincidense").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  });




  $('#enterempresa').click(function () {
password = document.getElementById("password_empresa").value;
password1 = document.getElementById("password1_empresa").value;
if (password == password1) {
  let password_ = password_empresa.value
  let password1_ = password1_empresa.value
  let email_ = email_empresa.value;
  let nome_ = nome_empresa.value;
  let nif_ = nif_empresa.value;
  let morada_ = morada_empresa.value;
  let cod_postal_ = codigopostal_empresa.value;
  let cidade_ = cidade_empresa.value;
  let tipo_ = "empresa";
  var fd = new FormData();
  var file = $('#img_empresa')[0].files[0];
  fd.append('img_empresa', file);
  fd.append('nome', nome_);
  fd.append('email',email_);
  fd.append('tipo', tipo_);
  fd.append('password', password_);
  fd.append('password1', password1_);
  fd.append('nif', nif_)
  fd.append('morada', morada_);
  fd.append('cod_postal',cod_postal_);
  fd.append('cidade_',cidade_);
  console.log (fd.get(file));
 
  window.alert(tipo);




  $.ajax({
    url: urlattime+'/user/register',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: fd,
    contentType: false,
            processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
      window.location.href = "login.html";
    }
    , error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
      window.alert('text status ' + textStatus + ', err ' + err)
      window.alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
    
  })

}
else {

  console.log(password + "" + password)
  document.getElementById("coincidense").style.visibility = "visible";
}
});
```

só a primeira funciona, (cliente) as outras nem retornam sucesso nem erro, o que pode ser?

Comment: abra a ferramenta de desenvolvedor do navegador (F12) e procure a aba de rede/network. Verifique lá se as chamadas estão sendo feitas, se estão com os valores corretos e se tem sucesso/erro

Comment: ja verifiquei, e nem sequer faz as chamadas, mais estranho é que ja esteve a funcionar..